# How to count the number of articles(i.e. in progress article and completed ) based on month in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have created a data table like below. Now I want to filter the data based on the month, such as in-progress articles per month and completed articles per month.

[image: refer my data table]

I have created a measure to show the completed articles till now.

Total Published Article = COUNTX(FILTER(MonthlyReport, MonthlyReport[Status] = "Completed"),MonthlyReport[Status])

another one is for incomplete articles based on the current month.

Current Month In Progress Articles = var inProgress= COUNTX(FILTER(MonthlyReport, MonthlyReport[Status] = "In Progress"),MonthlyReport[Status])
return
if(inProgress= BLANK(),0,inProgress)

for completed articles based on the current month.

Current Month Published Articles = Var CurrentMonth= MAX('MonthlyReport'[PublishDate].[Month])
Return
CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(MonthlyReport), Filter(MonthlyReport,MonthlyReport[PublishDate].[Month]=CurrentMonth))

How to filter the data according to the selected month?

For example, if I clicked on June(date slicer) then it will show the data a count of the total published articles, in-progress articles, and current month articles. i.e. For June, in progress=2, completed = 1.

So it would be helpful if anyone give me the correct formula.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First create a Calender table using Calendarauto() function.
Then use following measures to display completed and InProgress data
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]